# php accessing json array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a json string $text, that looks like this: `{"sections":[...],...}` i decode it to an array. when i loop through it using

```
$json = json_decode($text);
foreach($json as $x => $value) {
    echo $x."<br>";
}
```

i can access the the values as arrays, but when i try `$json['section']` i get an error. What is wrong with this access?

Comment: it would help if you include all the code in one short snippet to make bug reproduction easier. E.g. implement `$json['section']`.

Comment: json_deocde returns an object unless you pass second argument as true then it will return array.

Comment: Also, in your `$text` it is `sections`, but you try to access `section`

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Have you tried to dump `$json` to inspect the type of that variable?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is something like this than this work :

```
$a = '{"sections":[{ "a":"text" , "b":"text" } , { "a":"text1" , "b":"text1" }]}';
$json = json_decode($a);
foreach($json->sections as $x) {
    echo $x->a."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a second argument - **true**, it will tell **json_decode()** to return an array instead of an object

```
$json = json_decode($text, true);
```